# Springboot - JPA - não migra os relacionamentos no diagrama de entidade e relacionamento

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa-2.0, spring-jpa

Estou criando uma aplicação rest usando Springboot, JPA e como banco de dados o Mysql. Ela esta funcionamento bem, porém tem algo estranho quando entro no banco de dados.

Usei o Workbench para criar o diagrama de entidade relacional encima do esquema gerado pelo JPA, porém não migrou nenhum relacionamento entre as tabelas, o engraçado é que foram geradas todos os campos que deveriam ser chaves estrangeiras, mas não estão mapeadas como chaves.

Quando testo a aplicação roda perfeitamente, acho que quem esta mantendo a integridade dos relacionamentos no banco seja a própria aplicação antes de enviar os dados.

Como fazer para que os relacionamentos migrem também para o SGBD?

Abaixo esta a configuração do DB na aplicação:

```
#1 - Configurando o servidor banco de dados
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useSSL=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Por exemplo, abaixo segue as tabelas de Cidade e Estado que foram criadas no banco de dados através da JPA.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Abaixo seguem as duas classes:

Cidade:

```
@Entity
public class Cidade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String descricao;
    private Estado estado;
    private Date dt_insert;
    private Date dt_update;


    public Cidade () {

    }

    public Cidade(Long id, String descricao, Estado estado) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Estado getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public Date getDt_insert() {
        return dt_insert;
    }

    public void setDt_insert(Date dt_insert) {
        this.dt_insert = dt_insert;
    }

    public Date getDt_update() {
        return dt_update;
    }

    public void setDt_update(Date dt_update) {
        this.dt_update = dt_update;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        Date atual = new Date();
        this.dt_insert = atual;
        this.dt_update = atual;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        this.dt_update= new Date();
    }
}
```

Estado:

```
@Entity
public class Estado implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String sigla;
    private String descricao;

    private Date dt_insert;
    private Date dt_update;

    public Estado() {

    }

    public Estado(Long id, String sigla, String descricao) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.sigla = sigla;
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSigla() {
        return sigla;
    }

    public void setSigla(String sigla) {
        this.sigla = sigla;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public Date getDt_insert() {
        return dt_insert;
    }

    public void setDt_insert(Date dt_insert) {
        this.dt_insert = dt_insert;
    }

    public Date getDt_update() {
        return dt_update;
    }

    public void setDt_update(Date dt_update) {
        this.dt_update = dt_update;
    }


    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        Date atual = new Date();
        this.dt_insert = atual;
        this.dt_update = atual;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        this.dt_update= new Date();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Estado other = (Estado) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Como podem ver foi mapeado na classe cidade um relacionamento com a classe estado, porém unidirecional. Na imagem das tabelas não aparece a linha que mostra o tipo de relacionamento entre as duas.

Comment: Inclua um print do *status quo* do seu banco de dados e também algumas classes que demonstre como está sendo feito o seu relacionamento.

Comment: Tem certeza que não é um problema na ferramenta que vc usou? Você checou os scripts de criação das tabelas para ver se as constraints foram criadas?

Comment: Os relacionamento do JPA só criam constantes quando obrigatórios, se vc só adicionar o OneToMany ele não vai criar uma constante e indexar numa foreign key, é mesmo que declarar uma coluna e adicionar um relacionamento não obrigatório

Comment: Weslley Barbosa, tudo bem, como posso definir como obrigatória? Até porque faz parte de um requisito de negócio informar que obrigatoriamente a cidade tem que estar relacionada com o estado. Utilizei agora a anotação @NotNull na classe cidade no campo que se refere ao estado, assim obrigo que ele tenha um valor. Porém ainda sim não criou-se a FK. Como fazer com que ele se torne obrigatório?

Comment: @LeonardoLima, blz? Verifiquei sim os scripts, ele não esta criando as FK ele criar uma coluna como se fosse qualquer outra, porém não mapeia ela como Foreign Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir implementar a integridade referencial no banco de dados MYSql foi necessário que o JPA criasse as tabelas utilizando a engine InnoDB, para fazer isso alterei o dialeto dentro do application.properties e mandei gerar as tabelas. Deu certo, os relacionamentos no DB foram gerados.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```